# Return one row for a table Left join with another table has multirow with same ID

Tags: php, mysql

customers table:

[image]

notes table:

[image]

MY SQL query didn't work

```
SELECT * FROM customers LEFT JOIN notes  ON  customers.customer_id = notes.customer_id GROUP BY notes.customer_id
```

I want to return one row for customer_id 277 :
 Mr,Kevin, New notes, Service, 2017-06-17 12:37:28 
           New note 2, Lead, 2017-06-17 15:04:42

customers table left join with multi tables

[image]

Comment: What return with your query?

Comment: Is your table named note or notes?

Comment: In your Query you use both of note & notes

Comment: there no return. When insert another new note for same customer id I only want return one row  for that customer

Comment: notes table my miss type

Comment: you want all the records for the same customer_id showed  in a single row???

Comment: I strongly doubt this is actually what you want.  I suspect this is an XY problem, and you've gone down this path to solve a DIFFERENT problem.  Why don't you tell us what you're trying to do big picture, and we can probably help you do it in a much better way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a group_concat on  formatted  result for notes

```
   select a.customer_id, a.ttle, a.first_name, group_concat(t.note_row)
   from customer
   inner join ( 
      select customer_id, concat(note, ' ', note_type, ' ', note_date_added ) as note_row
      from notes 
     ) t on t.customer_id = a.customer_id
    group by a.customer_id, a.ttle, a.first_name
```